# Using PyPDF2 to write a new PDF - Fields are populating but not showing unless clicked on

Tags: python, pypdf

I am using PyPDF2 and a JSON file to write to an existing PDF and update its fields with the values in the JSON file. The fields all get updated, however they are not visible unless the user selects the field. Once they click away the data disappears again. If you interact with anything in the properties settings it will fix the issue but i don't want my users to have to do this each time.

This seems to be a common issue and the common solution seems to be using AcroForm but that has not been working for me. I've added it in `def set_need_appearances_writer(writer: PdfFileWriter)`. Perhaps I am using it wrong though.

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, request
from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter, PdfFileWriter 
from PyPDF2.generic import BooleanObject, NameObject, IndirectObject

from flask_cors import CORS

views = Blueprint('views', __name__)
CORS(views)

@views.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template("base.html")

def set_need_appearances_writer(writer: PdfFileWriter):
    # See 12.7.2 and 7.7.2 for more information: http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf
    try:
        catalog = writer._root_object
        # get the AcroForm tree
        if "/AcroForm" not in catalog:
            writer._root_object.update({
                NameObject("/AcroForm"): IndirectObject(len(writer._objects), 0, writer)
            })

        need_appearances = NameObject("/NeedAppearances")
        writer._root_object["/AcroForm"][need_appearances] = BooleanObject(True)
        # del writer._root_object["/AcroForm"]['NeedAppearances']
        return writer

    except Exception as e:
        print('set_need_appearances_writer() catch : ', repr(e))
        return writer

@views.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])

def submit():
    data = request.json
    reader = PdfReader("AF594.pdf")
    writer = PdfWriter()
    writer.add_page(reader.pages[0])
    lastNameFirst = data['sponsorLastName'] + ", " + data['sponsorFirstName']
    fullPhysicalAddress = data['sponsorAddress'] + ", " + data['city'] + ", " + data['state'] + " " + data['zipCode']
    data.update({ "lastNameFirst": lastNameFirst, "fullPhysicalAddress": fullPhysicalAddress})

    writer.update_page_form_field_values(writer.pages[0], data)

    set_need_appearances_writer(writer)  # Call set_need_appearances_writer() here
    fileName594 = data['sponsorFirstName'] + "_" + data['sponsorLastName'] +"_filled594.pdf"
    with open(fileName594, "wb") as output_stream:
        writer.write(output_stream)
    return "success"
```

Comment: Have you checked the file with another PDF viewer?